# Using Sleep AND LowPower.h

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I am trying to set up the low power module for an instance case, 
I have installed the low power library but when I am using the 
line

```
LowPower.powerDown (SlEEP_5S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF) ;
```

It is throwing an error stating that the 'SLEEP' was not declared in the scope. 
Any suggestion for that ? Do I have to include a library for sleep too ?

```
#include "LowPower.h"
  /// DON' t worry about the setup and loop, i have defined all those.
```

This set of code is in

```
  void Loop()  
    ...
    else           
    {
       LowPower.powerDown (SLEEP_10S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF) ;
```

Comment: `SlEEP_5S` ... should that be `SLEEP_5S` ?

Comment: Sorry ! I didnt get you

Comment: you can't see the difference between `SlEEP` and `SLEEP`?

Comment: nope i tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: i defined along with the package #include "LowPower.h"  #define SlEEP_5S, this leads me to an error that expected primary-expression before ','token

Comment: Void instead of void? An else without an if?  Your program will have many more problems right now. Note that the language is case sensitive.

Comment: I updated your code assuming that you typed it over (so changed void / else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 5 or 10 second sleep. You can't just arbitrarily choose how long to sleep for. The watchdog timer only has specific periods (defined by dividing the clock by a set amount) that it can sleep for:

```
enum period_t
{
    SLEEP_15MS,
    SLEEP_30MS,
    SLEEP_60MS,
    SLEEP_120MS,
    SLEEP_250MS,
    SLEEP_500MS,
    SLEEP_1S,
    SLEEP_2S,
    SLEEP_4S,
    SLEEP_8S,
    SLEEP_FOREVER
};
```

To sleep for 5 seconds you would need to sleep first for 4 seconds, then wake up, and then sleep for a further 1 second after that. For 10 seconds sleep for 8 seconds followed by 2 seconds.

Note that they aren't exact values, however, since the watchdog oscillator is very crude and varies wildly in frequency with both temperature and power supply voltage.